# ...ask a question to him

Tags: sentence-construction

I understand we normally say "I asked him a question", but I don't understand it is not correct to say "I asked a question to him.

By the same token, we need to say "I told him a story" but not "I told a story to him".

Is there anyone who can help me on this ? tks

Comment: We can say "I asked a question _of_ him", but it sounds rather formal and old-fashioned.

Comment: There is nothing grammatically wrong with "I told a story to him", although it is not the most common phrasing.  You can find many examples of *told a story to* [here.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22told+a+story+to%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALiCzsa00c5Wdj8-FkD4u5HNgHJygVTwmA%3A1658835112948&ei=qNDfYq3DOYDJptQP1f-iuA0&ved=0ahUKEwitt5etupb5AhWApIkEHdW_CNcQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22told+a+story+to%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEAMyBQghEKsCMgUIIRCrAjIFCCEQqwJQ6QlYixVglxdoAHAAeACAAVmIAd8BkgEBM5gBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-books)

Comment: Tks Stangdon… how about “ ask a question to him “ ? Is it ok to say this way ？ tks

Comment: You _pose_ a question to him, not ask.

Comment: Tks mdewey  but why we cannot say “ask a question to him “ ? Please don’t misunderstand I am stubborn. I need grammatical answer so that I can explain to some kids. 

Comment: @Kevin I don't think there is an answer besides "Because that is how English works".  Some verbs take prepositions and some do not.  For example, you "tell him", but you "say **to** him"; "tell *to* him" or "say him" are wrong.

Comment: Tks stangdon …. I understand

Answer (score 1):

The usage of *of and to* change the meaning of what you are saying.

- **Ask of** is to ask someone a question.  To an AmE speaker, *ask of* sounds very stuffy.  *I asked of Robert whether [or not] he had gone on vacation.*  Instead of including *of* we usually drop it and say, *I asked Robert whether he....*
- **Ask to** is to request someone to do something or to request you be allowed to do something. *I asked to go with Robert on his vacation.*
- **Tell of** is to speak of a particular thing.  *Robert entertained us by telling of his adventures in Bali.*
- **Tell to** is to say something directly to another person.  *Robert was told to return home after his visa expired.*